# The javascript function doesn't work when I try to Populate <g:select> using Ajax in Grails?

Tags: ajax, json, grails

I have two SELECT box in my GSP page.And I want to change the values of one SELECT box depends on another SELECT box Onchange on the same page without doing a refresh.

Create.gsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
    <html>
    <g:javascript library="jQuery"/>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <g:form action="" class="inputform">
     <div class="body">
     <div id="cntrls" style="height:550px;width: 600px;border: 1px solid #cccccc;float: left;position: relative;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Layout or Controls :</td>
        <td><g:select name="layout" id="layout" from="['Layout Component','Control']" noSelection="['0':'----Select----']" onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'FormCreator', action:'populateControls', onComplete:'cntrl_type(e)',params:'\'filter=\' + escape(this.value)' )}"/></td>
                    </tr>
    <tr>  
      <td>Control Type :</td>  
      <td><g:select name="cntrl_type" id="cntrl_type" from="" noSelection="['0':'----Select----']" value="${formCreator.cntrl_type }"/></td>
      </tr>   
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </g:form>
    </body>
    </html>
<g:javascript>
function cntrl_type(e) {    
    var cntrls = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")") 
    if (cntrls) { 
var rselect = document.getElementById("cntrl_type")
    while (l > 0) { l-- rselect.remove(l) 
}

    // Rebuild the select 
    for (var i=0; i < cntrls.length; i++) { 
        var cntr = cntrls[i] 
        var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
        opt.text = cntr.name
        opt.value = cntr.name
        try { 
            rselect.add(opt, null) 
} 
            catch(ex) { 
                rselect.add(opt) // IE only 
                }
             } 
         } 
     }

    // This is called when the page loads to initialize city 
    var zselect = document.getElementById("layout") 
    var zopt = zselect.options[zselect.selectedIndex] 
    ${remoteFunction(controller:"FormCreator", action:"populateControls", params:"'filter=' + zopt.value", onComplete:"cntrl_type(e)")}
</g:javascript>
```

Following handler for retrieving the list.

```
package autogeneration

import grails.converters.JSON

class FormCreatorController {
def populateControls={      
        def list
        if(params.filter=="Layout Component"){
            list=['Div']
        }else if(params.filter=="Control"){
        list=['Text Type','Combo Box','Text Area','Submit','Label']
    }       
        render list as JSON
}
```

The populateControls function works when I change the value of first select box.But the javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe the way you are going about this is very backwards. One of your issues may be that you are using cntr.name, while you aren't passing name down. It's just an array of strings. Try just cntr instead of cntr.name?

```
    cntrl_type(e) {    
    var cntrls = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")")         
    for (var i=0; i < cntrls.length; i++) { 
    var cntr = cntrls[i] 
    opt.text = cntr.name
```

Also, if you are using JQuery its "data", not "e". You don't need the eval either. Also change it so it calls the function onSuccess instead of onComplete.

```
cntrl_type(e) {    
var cntrls = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")")
```

Also, this is lazy.

```
def list
```

Do this instead:

```
List<String> list = []
```